# How to convert []string to []float64 in Golang?

Tags: go

I'm new to programming, and trying to write a simple average program in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var numbers []float64
var sum float64 = 0

func main() {

    if len(os.Args) > 1 {

        numbers = os.Args[1:]

    }

    fmt.Println("Numbers are: ", numbers)
    for _, value := range numbers {
        sum += value
    }

}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/TWNltPO71N

when I build the program, I got this error:

```
prog.go:15: cannot use os.Args[1:] (type []string) as type []float64 in assignment
[process exited with non-zero status]
```

So how to convert a slice of string to a slice of float numbers? Can I map a convert function to the slice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to convert string to float64 using [strconv.ParseFloat](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat) function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

var numbers []float64
var sum float64 = 0

func main() {

    if len(os.Args) <= 1 {
        return
    }

    for _, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
        if n, err := strconv.ParseFloat(arg, 64); err == nil {
            numbers = append(numbers, n)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Numbers are: ", numbers)
    for _, value := range numbers {
        sum += value
    }

}
```

Comment: I would not use `append()` here; the length of the array is known and we can just allocate it.

Comment: Array size is know iff failed float parsing should 'abort' loop... I really don't like that you have changed the meaning of my code with your edit :/

Comment: Please undo my edit if you do not like it. It's okay.

Comment: Thank you very much. 1. `for` iterates over a slice is really simple yet useful. I guess this is the counterpart of `map` in a functional language. 2. `strconv.ParseFloat` not only convert the string to float, it also handles the separators - a mix use of comma and space, even irrelevant chars - `strconv` just done right. It's amazing! `Go` is simple and powerful.

Answer (score 2):

It can't convert because `string` and `int` are not compatible.

Instead of having the `numbers` slice, just iterate over `os.Args[1:]`, using [ParseFloat](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat) from the `strconv` package.

```
fmt.Print("Numbers are: ")
for _, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
    fmt.Print(arg, " ")
    value, err := strconv.ParseFloat(arg, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    sum += value
}
```